# Conditional data extraction from multiple dataframes

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

I am currently trying to read out data from multiple data frames (`A1-A8`), which all have the same structure, with a for loop. Within the for loop, I would like to extract data meeting a certain condition (in this case, a specific depth). I tried this with subset and if-else. The problem I am facing is, that in case this condition is not met, the for loop is interrupted and the following steps are not carried out. Here's the example:

```
Depth <- c(40,60,70,80,85,90)
D2H <- c(-60,-65,-63,-67,-58,-66)
A1 <- data.frame(Depth, D2H) 

for (i in 1:8) {
    Ax <- get((paste("A",i,sep="")))# reads in the dataframe
    A_40[i] <- subset(Ax$D2H, Ax$Depth == 40) #writes the value of D2H at depth 40 into the new vector
    A_60[i] <- subset(Ax$D2H, Ax$Depth == 60)
}
```

So if for example data frame `A3` doesn't contain `Depth = 40`, the for loop is interrupted. How can I overcome this problem? Wrong approach?

I hope I described the problem well enough, if not, let me know and I will extend the description. I am highly thankful for any recommendations.

Comment: so are you getting an error with this approach? You can try using the `which()` to find the rows which satisfy the conditions and then check the number of satisfactory rows using `length()`. Only if the length is greater than 'zero', try the `subset()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to consider using a list of data frames, something like this might achieve what you're after

```
Depth <- c(40,60,70,80,85,90)
D2H <- c(-60,-65,-63,-67,-58,-66)
A1 <- data.frame(Depth, D2H) 

set.seed(123) ## these would be your other 7 data frames in your case
A2 <- A1[sample(nrow(A1), nrow(A1), replace = TRUE),]
A3 <- A1[sample(nrow(A1), nrow(A1), replace = TRUE),]
A4 <- A1[sample(nrow(A1), nrow(A1), replace = TRUE),]
A5 <- A1[sample(nrow(A1), nrow(A1), replace = TRUE),]
A6 <- A1[sample(nrow(A1), nrow(A1), replace = TRUE),]
A7 <- A1[sample(nrow(A1), nrow(A1), replace = TRUE),]
A8 <- A1[sample(nrow(A1), nrow(A1), replace = TRUE),]

mydflist <- list(A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8)

newlist40 <- lapply(mydflist, function(x) subset(x$D2H, x$Depth == 40))
newlist60 <- lapply(mydflist, function(x) subset(x$D2H, x$Depth == 60))
```

**EDIT**

```
newlist40.b <- lapply(newlist40, function(x) if(length(x)==0) x <- NA else x)
newlist40.final <- unlist(lapply(newlist40.b, unique)) ## if you want unique values from each array in list
# newlist40.final <- unlist(newlist40.b) # if you don't

newlist60.b <- lapply(newlist60, function(x) if(length(x)==0) x <- NA else x)
newlist60.final <- unlist(lapply(newlist60.b, unique)) ## if you want unique values from each array in list
# newlist60.final <- unlist(newlist60.b) # if you don't
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! The only issue is that I get a list instead of a vector as a result. Is there a way to get a vector directly?

Comment: you want a vector with unique values whatever the data.frame they're coming from? what should the vector look like?

Comment: basically a vector with the 8 values I was reading out of the dataframes, best with NA if there was none.

Comment: Yes, very nice! Thanks alot! Great help!

Comment: consider accepting the question if that solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think simone's way is the best answer, but if you are determined to use a for loop, the fix here has to do with just writing an if condition.

```
for (i in 1:8) {
  Ax <- get((paste("A",i,sep="")))# reads in the dataframe

    if (length(subset(Ax$D2H, Ax$Depth == 40) > 0) {A_40[i] <- subset(Ax$D2H, Ax$Depth == 40)
    } else { A_40[i] = NA }

    if (length(subset(Ax$D2H, Ax$Depth == 60) > 0) {A_60[i] <- subset(Ax$D2H, Ax$Depth == 60)
    } else { A_60[i] = NA }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this also works great.  I´ve been trying to use the if function, but couldn´t figure out how. This looks much better! Thanks!